# Find index number of a grid from X,Y coordinates (with a twist)

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a procedurally generated grid, let's say 22 by 22 cells in size. For each cell in the grid, it may have a state of **on** or **off**. Only cells marked as **on** have an index number. So at the end of the grid with 484 actual cells, there may only be a total indexed number of 30 or so.

So, given that I know the size of the grid exactly, I have the X,Y coords of an indexed cell, and I know how many indexed cells there are in total, is it possible to get the index of the cell exactly?

I'm thinking I need to track the number of unindexed cells as they're added to the grid as well to achieve what I want, but I'm really drawing a blank on how I would work that in. I feel like this answer is much simpler than it seems, and I'm allowing too many pointless variables into my attempt to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `m` and `n` be the dimensions of the grid.

Let `k` be the number of indexed cells.

**If it's a sparse grid,** where few cells are marked on, you could compute the index number in O(log k). Maintain a list of indexed cells, sorted and represented by `(row*n) + col`, where `row` and `col` are zero-based. Turning on/off a cell is O(k) to maintain the list. To compute the index number for (row,col), do a binary search for `(row*n)+col`. The list index of the item found is the index you seek.

**If cells are never or infrequently toggled,** you might follow that same approach even for a non-sparse grid, paying for O(k) list maintenance only during initialization or infrequently.

**If it's a small grid,** a simple implementation would be O(m * n). Traverse the grid, counting indexed cells as you go, until you get to the desired cell. However, it it's a large grid, this becomes the *naive* implementation.

**Otherwise,** you could improve that to O(m + n) by keeping counts of the number of indexed cells per row. Whenever a cell is turned on/off, increment/decrement that row's count in O(1). To compute the index, traverse the prior rows in O(m), summing up those counts. Then traverse the columns in the final row, in O(n), until the desired cell is reached, counting that partial row's indexed cells. Add that count to the sum from prior rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to try to work this in as I build out the script.